# Search mercurial repository for changes in a certain path

Tags: version-control, mercurial, repository, tortoisehg

I have a site developed using Yii framework, and I want to upgrade the framework from version 1.1.8 to 1.1.11. I have made framework modifications that went into 1.1.11, but others didn't and I don't remember exactly which ones they are.

Is there a way to search for all the changes in a Mercurial repository made in a certain path?
The framework sits in ./yiiframework directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a path to the `hg log` command:

```
hg log path/to/foo
```

Answer (score 0):

While @David answer is technically correct, it's wrong ideologically, and I'll answer on not-asked-question

**"How to maintain my patches on top of changing upstream codebase"**

which is really *your business-task*

For Mercurial this is rather easy job, where you perform only part of work "merge parallel changes", which can't be done automatically by SCM.

Short HowTo

- You use Mercurial repository
- You'll use at least 2 long-life named branches: "default" for upsteam code /if upstream is also hg/ or any other name for manually added upstream and, f.e. "My" branch for local patches
- Your repo can be started with upstream vanilla code of 1.1.8 (rev 1)
- You perform all your changes in WC on top of 1.1.8 and branch changed in My branch (rev 2)
- Return back to rev 1 and sync codebase with 1.1.11, commit to default branch (rev 3)
- Update to rev 2 and merge branches (default to My), resolve possible conflicts

After this actions your have 1.1.11 **with changes inherited from your 1.1.8**

Future workflow
* Work on own branch only
* Pull from upstream (if you can) into default or update default by hand
* Merge into My, when it's needed

PS - More complex workflow *may* assume and admit using MQ-patches on top of single branch