# Conflicts on mercurial vendor branches merge

Tags: mercurial, branch, conflict, vendor

Some days ago I decided to adopt a "vendor branching" in my current project in order to make 3rd party libraries updates, so I tried to do a similar process as described in this question:
[Vendor Branching, Mercurial Style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997600/vendor-branching-mercurial-style?rq=1)

Now I basically have this scenario:

- `http://host/hg/vendor` - contains version 2.0 of the library and an update to version 3.0
- `http://host/hg/project` - this is the main project and **already** contains version 2.0  of the library with some local changes (which previously was version 1.0 and was updated manually).

In the vendor repo I :

- Created a branch named "vendor-lib"
- Added added `lib-2.0` and tag `lib-2.0`
- Added (addremove) `lib-3.0` and tag `lib-3.0`

In my project repo I:

- Pulled the external vendor repo `hg pull ../vendor -f`
- from default I did `hg merge vendor-lib`

Now comes the problem, all files are conflicted.
In the conflict, Local and Other are normal files, but Base is empty. So the solution is adding one of them or setting the file as completely empty.
I assume that this happens because the pulled branch `vendor-lib` hasn't any common parent with default.

I don't know if maybe there is a way to set a common parent between both branches, or just merging the delta between `lib-2.0` and `lib-3.0` to default.

I'd really appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need this when you can use nuget? If your vendor doesn't have a nuget package, you can create and host yourself.

Comment: [This my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12875663) you may use as starting point